# How to flip a Div's Contents

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a list of “comments” that are pulled from a string using ajax. The problem is the comments are in order from first to last. I would like to display them last to first. The div below is what it looks like when there is comments within the “JJ_Comments” div.

```
    <div id="JJ_Comments">
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate"> Nov 11 2019  3:27PM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Bulk upload project</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 19 2019  8:43AM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019  9:01AM: NAME HERE </div>
                   <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
                   </div>   
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019  5:38PM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> ASBUILT DESIGN COMPLETE - QC COMPLETED</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019 10:05PM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Stuff <div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 21 2019  8:55AM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 21 2019  8:58AM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Job has been posted</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Below is what I want it to be “flipped” too.

```
    <div id="JJ_Comments">
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 21 2019  8:58AM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Job has been posted</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 21 2019  8:55AM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019 10:05PM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Stuff <div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019  5:38PM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> ASBUILT DESIGN COMPLETE - QC COMPLETED</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019  9:01AM: NAME HERE </div>
                   <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
                   </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 19 2019  8:43AM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
    <div class="JJ_CommentDate"> Nov 11 2019  3:27PM: NAME HERE </div>
    <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Bulk upload project</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you saving your array of comments? I'm assuming in some sort of database? Because such a task would be far simpler to solve from SQL (or similar) if you have it available to you.

Comment: I dont have access to the database if there is one so sadly, it has to be jquery/javascript or a html/css that I am missing

Comment: use the array.reverse();

Comment: TBH Array was the wrong word to use, its more of a string. It sends a string of the HTML code, but I modified it using replace alot.

Comment: Hey, on a side note, doing anything with the supplied HTML might be a bit of an issue as the `id`'s - `JJ_CommentDate`, `JJ_CommentText` are not unique, and in fact are repeated multiple times. Unless this is a simplification of your actual code?

Comment: Each one is wrapped in a "JJ_Comment" class div. Too get each comment it would be easy just to run through all "JJ_Comment" classes. So kinda simplification of the code

Comment: Having duplicate IDs is not valid and can often lead to problems. Furthermore, please share your code that's generating this, or your attempt to solve it. Generally people are much more willing to help you than to write your code for you.

Comment: The use of `JJ_Comment` is great, but every `id` in a HTML page **MUST** be unique. So having 2 or more comments with the id `JJ_CommentDate` or `JJ_CommentText` means your HTML is invalid

Comment: My solution was simple but not what I would like, I made this to get information not really a "solution". I could simply irreterate through each comment in the div grabbing last to first and append it to a new div but I was looking for a similar solution. This code is invalid because its a demonstration. Yes ID's should be unique but do not have too. This is for a tool I am making at work to allow users to better view the content. I was just looking for a similar, cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you're looking for a better solution. But unless you supply valid HTML, it's going to be nearly impossible to generate a solution for you.

Comment: ID's are now gone because they are not needed. Valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've come up with.

1. Select all comments
2. Convert this list to an Array
3. Reverse the array direction
4. Append the elements to the top of the comments container

**Select All Comments**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('JJ_Comment')
```

**Convert this list to an Array**

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('JJ_Comment'))+
```

**Reverse the array direction**

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('JJ_Comment')).reverse();
```

**Append the elements to the top of the comments container**

```
commentSection.appendChild(element);
```

Please note, your HTML is still invalid, with two unclosed `div` at the end of your `HTML`.

My solution will get each `JJ_Comment` element and does not rely on the structure of your outer `HTML` container being valid, or sound. I think this is probably the best solution if you are unsure if your outer `HTML` container is going to be completely valid `HTML`.

```js
var comments = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('JJ_Comment')).reverse();
var commentSection = document.getElementById('JJ_Comments');

comments.forEach(function(element) {
  commentSection.appendChild(element);
});
```

```html
  <div id="JJ_Comments">
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
      <div class="JJ_CommentDate"> Nov 11 2019 3:27PM: NAME HERE </div>
      <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Bulk upload project</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
      <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 19 2019 8:43AM: NAME HERE </div>
      <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
      <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019 9:01AM: NAME HERE </div>
      <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
      <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019 5:38PM: NAME HERE </div>
      <div class="JJ_CommentText"> ASBUILT DESIGN COMPLETE - QC COMPLETED</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
      <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019 10:05PM: NAME HERE </div>
      <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Stuff <div>
        </div>
        <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
          <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 21 2019 8:55AM: NAME HERE </div>
          <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
        </div>
        <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
          <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 21 2019 8:58AM: NAME HERE </div>
          <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Job has been posted</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Great Job, Thank you. I will also give my solution to my own question.

Answer (score 3):

Please correct your HTML as you are missing two closing `</div>` at the bottom and apply the solution below. It is very easy to do this with CSS. take a look at the snippet below.

However, if you you are parsing data with AJAX call, you might want to reverse the loop logic with the highest value of number of data being fetched.

```css
#JJ_Comments{
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="JJ_Comments">
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
        <div class="JJ_CommentDate"> Nov 11 2019 3:27PM: NAME HERE </div>
        <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Bulk upload project</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
        <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 19 2019 8:43AM: NAME HERE </div>
        <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
        <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019 9:01AM: NAME HERE </div>
        <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
        <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019 5:38PM: NAME HERE </div>
        <div class="JJ_CommentText"> ASBUILT DESIGN COMPLETE - QC COMPLETED</div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
        <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 20 2019 10:05PM: NAME HERE </div>
        <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Stuff
            <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
                <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 21 2019 8:55AM: NAME HERE </div>
                <div class="JJ_CommentText"> RESOURCE CONSTRAINT</div>
            </div>
            <div onclick="copyComment(this)" class="JJ_Comment">
                <div class="JJ_CommentDate">Nov 21 2019 8:58AM: NAME HERE </div>
                <div class="JJ_CommentText"> Job has been posted</div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution functionally works, but doesn't account for potentially nested invalid HTML. Like the nested comments `Nov 20` and `Nov 21`. I think they wanted `Nov 21` to be the first comment as it was reversed.. but the HTML isn't nested correctly (or something), so this functionally works but doesn't render the result they were after :( (+1 because this is a neat solution for valid HTML)

Answer (score 0):

First create a new "Comment Holding Container".

`<div id='JJ_CommentsHidden'></div>`

Then place all the comments from first to last. (Default)

`$('#JJ_CommentsHidden').html(comments_ftl);`

Then grab the length of all the comments in that container.

`commentAmount = $('#JJ_CommentsHidden').children('.JJ_Comment').length;`

Set a blank string variable to append into.

`final = '';`

Then make a reverse for loop to irrederate over all of the comments from least to first, grab the outterhtml and append to the string.

```
           for (i = commentAmount - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
              final = final.concat($('#JJ_CommentsHidden').children('.JJ_Comment').eq(i).prop('outerHTML'));
              if(i==0){
                return $('#JJ_Comments').html(final);
              }
            }
```

Check if the irreteration is 0 and if it is then place it in the html of the div you wish to display.

Together:

```
           $('#JJ_CommentsHidden').html(text);
           commentAmount = $('#JJ_CommentsHidden').children('.JJ_Comment').length;
           final = '';
           for (i = commentAmount - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
              final = final.concat($('#JJ_CommentsHidden').children('.JJ_Comment').eq(i).prop('outerHTML'));
              if(i==0){
                return $('#JJ_Comments').html(final);
              }
            }
```